# Database lock contention upon collection creation

Tags: mongodb

Our mongo setup:

1) mongodb version 3.2.22
2) WiredTiger storage engine
3) 1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 arbiter replica set
4) dataset size is ~ 160GB (+gridFS)
5) system: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, vcpus:8, RAM: 56, 25600 MAX IOPS

Our db stats:

```
{
 "db" : "name",
 "collections" : 592918,
 "objects" : 2566552,
 "avgObjSize" : 57148.94103684632,
 "dataSize" : 146675728916,
 "storageSize" : 167547809792,
 "numExtents" : 0,
 "indexes" : 671752,
 "indexSize" : 13323071488,
 "ok" : 1
}
```

Here is gist with db.serverStatus() https://gist.github.com/d3sire/91ebe81cb7eb8d19db3c9f472e9dff6e

The problem:

Suddenly, our requests started to take really long time(up to a minute!). Upon, further investigation I have determined the use case to "trigger" these slow requests. Basically, whenever the new collection is created (with normal insert or even by using createCollection) all other queries are getting stacked up in a queue and are really slow.

Steps to reproduce for us are following:

1) run db.coll_new_name.insert({"test":"test"})

2) in another shell run db.serverStatus().globalLock and it will show

```
"currentQueue" : {
    "total" :27,
    "readers" : 26,
    "writers" : 1
},
```

Judging by mongo documentation the amount of collections in WiredTiger is not limited.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I am not a mongo expert but 600000 collections seems very huge number, whatever the doc says. My feeling is (sorry) to change conception, and to merge collections and add an indexed field containing the old collection name, or any short well known value.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Slim, but unfortuentely changing this concept right now is not an option.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?, Also how frequently are collections created in your database

Comment: @PriyankaKariya we are using XFS, collection creations is happening every time new user registers.

Comment: I would agree with slim, let the current process continue. merge all the user collection to the new single collection and move to that approach. Because even if you are adding one document per collection you are increasing index overhead and namespace. Look into it if possible. If not now this might create issue in near future.